# Solana add instructions to VersionedTransaction in python

Tags: python-3.x, solana

I have a raw_transaction of type VersionedTransaction for which I'd like to add instructions.
The raw_transaction.message.instructions are CompiledInstruction, and I have raw Instruction that I'd like to add. If I just do raw_transaction.message.instructions.append(instruction1), it oes not work as instruciton1 is not compiled.
Any idea how I could do that please?